# Is it possible to have two Ultimate Teams on one account?

Tags: fifa-14

I have Fifa 14 on the PS3. My husband has been playing and has his own team and players, etc. I'd like to play too, but I don't want to use his team or players, I want to build my own team. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. But, I suggest that you use two different squads. First, go to the squad menu, then enter the squad selector, third click to "Create a New Squad". So, you can play like two different teams(squads) in this way.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can have 2 ultimate teams. All you need is two different PS accounts. When you log in with the one your husband doesn't use, you go to fifa and select ultimate team. Then, since you're on a different account, there'll be none of your husband's squad, only a new squad for you to play with and improve.